# PHP Keeping URL parameters when clicking a hyperlink to add GET variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to have a hyperlink that will add a new/additional GET variable to the URL, but will not remove any existing GET variables or anchor tags. So, if my URL is any of the following:

```
http://example.com/index.html?color=blue
http://example.com/index.html?color=blue&type=shirt
http://example.com/index.html?color=blue#reviews
```

...and I click the link, such as:

```
<a href="?size=large">Large</a>
```

... the URL should be updated to:

```
http://example.com/index.html?color=blue&size=large
http://example.com/index.html?color=blue&type=shirt&size=large
http://example.com/index.html?color=blue&size=large#reviews
```

Right now, if I make a link as above, it will remove all existing GET variables and anchor tags from the existing URL.

What's the fix?

Comment: the fix is a proper construction of the url in your inner pages based on the already existing url. simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<a href="?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&size=large">Large</a>
```

[See `QUERY_STRING`.](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1):

much like Samsquanch's answer but try replacing SERVER with GET

```
<a href="?<?php echo $_GET['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&size=large">Large</a>
```